# Weird sound playing on an backing track in A

Tags: scales, amplifiers, homerecording

I have a hard time figuring out what is wrong with my playing when trying some impro stuff in blues. I am fairly new to playing guitar on a more serious level now. Just started with blues because I love it so much.
I did the following:

- Find a blues backing track in A
- Connecting it via Bluetooth to my Blackstar Fly 3 mini amp
- Connecting my guitar made sure the tuning is in E (standard)
- Put my Shure SM57 mic in front of the amp
- Recording with Cubase LE (without any effects)
- Playing along the backing track with the A Blues Scale

When playing I do not hear much wrong to be honest. But as I start listening to the recording it sounds very odd to me like I was playing a wrong scale or whatever. But I really am sure I used the A Blues scale here I swear ;)

Can anybody might figure out what the actual problem is? Here is the link to listen to the track (sorry for having to listen to it!): https://vocaroo.com/i/s0ZBPQsOMs12

Comment: You should have added an open chord that we could check your tuning. it sounds as the g- and b-string are not well tuned. or are you pulling with your fingers on the frets? or manipulatingon the tremolo system?

Comment: Hm actually none mentioned. I have no tremolo and I don't think I mess with the frets. I gonna try to re-record it and this time double check the tuning if you really think that might be the issue here.

Comment: Welcome to the wonder world of hearing yourself recorded. It truly is the best for pointing out issues you don't hear when you are playing. They exist. And recording yourself just lets you hear them without being distracted by playing. Is your action very high? Sound like you are bending the strings slightly. If they truly are in tune and intonated.

Answer (score 2):

I suspected it was a tuning problem at first, and after listening to your recording I could confirm it. You are using the right scale, but the higher notes are a bit out of tune. Some possibilities:

- The E string, and maybe the B string are not well tuned. You said you made sure the tuning is right, so it's probably not that.
- You guitar is not well intonated. The tuning of the open string is right, but the fretted notes are out of tune. You can easily test this one by tuning the open E string, and checking if the 12th fret is also a perfectly tuned E, for example.
- If you are using very light gauge, the pressure of your finger on the fret could be stretching the strings, making them sound sharper. You can test this by playing any fret really gently and gradually increasing pressure.  If the sound gets gradually sharper, that's it.